# NodeJS await/async not working in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently working on a validation module in nodeJs and I cannot seem to understand how or why does the async/await does not work in my current module.

In the module I should be able to have more than one validation exports ex: Forms, Data etc.

Each object should have more that one validation functions, ex: forms should have register, login, add etc...

This is my approach

```
var forms = {
    validation: {
        status: true,
        data: {},
        error: {}
    },

    register: async(data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var validation = forms.validation;

        try {
            const errorMessages = await forms.getErrorMessages('register');
            ...
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    }),


    getErrorMessages: (key) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Errors.
        findOne({ type: 'validation', 'identifier': key }).
        select('content').
        populate('content'). // only works if we pushed refs to children
        exec(function(err, contentObj) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            var errorMessages = {};
            const contentArray = contentObj.content;
            for (var i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
                var key = contentArray[i].identifier,
                    message = contentArray[i].message;
                errorMessages[key] = message;
            }
            resolve(errorMessages);
        });
    }),

};
exports.forms = forms;
```

Now at the `register` function, which is defined as `async` function, in `try`  I have that `await forms.getErrorMessages('register')` which should return the validation error messages from the database... The function works, it's defined to return a promise but I always get `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` for the function...

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Node are you running this on?

Comment: @LukasKnuth  v7.10.1

Comment: The SyntaxError you're seeing should include additional info like a line-number. Can  you mark the line in your code and add the full exception, too?

Comment: /home/sabin/Work/purchase/napi/api/services/validationService.js:74
            const errorMessages = await forms.getErrorMessages('register');
                                       
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

The unexpected identifier is marked at 'forms'

Comment: When in an `async` function you don't need to create a new promise unless you are resolving a callback.  Mongoose can return promises as well, so you don't need to use it's callback interface either

Comment: @Matt you are referring to the promise from `register` or `getErrorMessages` ?

Comment: Both actually, The mongoose query can return a promise by using `.exec().then()`.  `register` is also dealing only in promises so you get  the promise and `reject(error)` for free just by using `async`, any thrown error will be captured.

Comment: @Matt for the `register` function I use the promise because I have the following logic. The register request is routed to the usersController where it awaits the validation module to process the request. As for the second one could you please post a response with the `.exec().then()` solution so I could better understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create `new Promise`s when you already have a Promise. That is only required when you are converting some API that is not a promise into a promise.

Mongoose can return promises natively too, and the `async` function will allow any errors that are thrown to bubble up through the promises.

```
var forms = {

    validation: {
        status: true,
        data: {},
        error: {}
    },

    register: async (data) => {
        var validation = this.validation;
        const errorMessages = await this.getErrorMessages('register');
        ...
    },


    getErrorMessages: async (key) => {
        let contentObj = await Errors.findOne({ type: 'validation', 'identifier': key })
            .select('content')
            .populate('content') // only works if we pushed refs to children
            .exec()

        let errorMessages = {};
        const contentArray = contentObj.content;
        for (var i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++) {
             let key = contentArray[i].identifier;
             let message = contentArray[i].message;
             errorMessages[key] = message;
        }
        return errorMessages;

    }

};
exports.forms = forms;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, it will take a time to understand where the promise should be put and where not...

Comment: Whenever you use `async` you get a new promise, it's not exactly like `new Promise` as you can't `resolve` values or `reject` errors but you can `return` values and `throw` errors.

Comment: You might still need `new Promise` when you are converting a stream or callback into a promise, but it's getting rarer

Comment: Thanks for the info